# How to remove Qt widget (with layout) space

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget, qboxlayout

I have written a program that uses widgets as container (for other widgets). Because the contents of the container varies along the program life, the container widget has a layout associated to it so it resizes properly.

The problem is that the container seems to consume some space.

In the following program, I have reproduced the problem:

I have a group with a few labels, where one of them is included in a container (the widget `w` -and its layout `t`- includes the label "*what is that extra space?*").

My goal is to get the spacing between all labels the same, regardless whether they are in containers or not (the container should not consume space).

I have also tried to color the different parts of the widgets.

- Where is my padding?
- What is the extra space between the widgets (between the blue)?
- How do I remove it?

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMdiArea>
#include <QMdiSubWindow>

#include <stdlib.h>

QMdiArea* g1;
QGroupBox* g1a;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow* main_window = new(QMainWindow);
    main_window->resize(200, 200);
    main_window->setWindowTitle("Hello");

    g1a = new QGroupBox("G1A", g1);
    QVBoxLayout *g1a_l = new QVBoxLayout(g1a);
    g1a_l->setSpacing(0);
    main_window->setCentralWidget(g1a);

    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label1"));
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label2"));
    QWidget* w=new QWidget(0);
    w->setStyleSheet( "border: 2 solid blue; padding: 2 solid yellow;" );
    QVBoxLayout* t=new QVBoxLayout(w);
    t->setSpacing(0);
    t->addWidget(new QLabel("What is that extra space??",w));

    g1a_l->addWidget(w);
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label3"));
    g1a_l->addWidget((QLabel*)new QLabel(" Nice Label4"));

    //sub_window->adjustSize();
    main_window->show(); //How to I get that to recaclulate the size of its contents?
    
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing extra spacing around QWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017789/removing-extra-spacing-around-qwidget)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [contentsMargin](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt/qlayout.html#contentsMargins)

To remove it:

```
t->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The space you referring to is a content margin. The docu [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model) describes how the widgets are drawn. To get rid of that extra space you have to call:

```
widget->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I believe the end result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The method I recall to control spacing is to add dedicated `QSpacerItem` items between the widgets.

But I'm first trying to figure out what `w` is doing. Why not call `g1a_l->addLayout(t);` directly?