# Removing extra spacing around QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

How to remove extra spacing around QWidget?

Here's the simple example. The widget's space is grey; you see, there's some space (about 0.3-0.4 cm) around the content of it (image, text and button).

Widget's space was highlighted by

```
setAutoFillBackground(true);
QPalette pal(palette());
pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, QColor("#e5e5e5"));
setPalette(pal);
```

[image: Example]

Here's the content (highlighted by running `setStyleSheet( "background-color: red");` for the whole widget.

[image: Example]

By 'removing extra spacing' I mean removing about 0.2-0.3 cm of grey space around content.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change the contents margins of the layout you added the QWidget to and any other layout you wish to change by using the method [`setContentsMargins()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins).

Answer (score 3):

There are two functions that you can use to get rid of all the spacing in your layout:

```
1)QLayout::setMargin(0)
2)QLayout::setSpacing(0)
```

Comment: Even though `::setMargin()` is obsolete, I still like using it cause of its convenience:)