# Qt remove margins

Tags: c++, css, qt, widget, margins

I am currently using a QMainWindow widget and I would like to remove margins around the widget inside. I success to remove margins for window borders but not for the widgets inside my window.

Here is my code, for example :

```
this->mainWidget = new QWidget(this);
this->mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
QLabel *foo = new QLabel("foo", this);
QLabel *bar = new QLabel("bar", this);

mainLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // Remove margins for window borders

this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

foo->setStyleSheet("background-color: green");
bar->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
foo->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // Has no effect
bar->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // Has no effect

this->mainLayout->addWidget(foo);
this->mainLayout->addWidget(bar);

this->mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
this->setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
```

And here is what it rendered :

[image: Window render]

I would like to remove the white part between the two widgets.

Have you an idea how to make that kind of things ?

Thank you.

Comment: Side note: you're using `this->...` for all your member accesses except one (the setContentMargin for the mainLayout) - either do it for all, or for none, but leaving just that one without the explicit qualification looks weird - makes you wonder whether we're talking about two different things or not.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129324/qt-widget-with-layout-space-what-is-it-how-to-remove and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017789/removing-extra-spacing-around-qwidget

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply need to set the [spacing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlayout.html#spacing-prop) attribute of your box layout to zero:

```
 this->mainLayout->setSpacing(0);
```