# Changing the background colour of label in QT

Tags: qt, background-color

I have a main window and a label on it. This has to be displayed on full screen. A data will displayed on label. The background should be black and text needs to be white. I am receiving data like `1 or 2 or 3` via serial and I am fetching the related text of `1 or 2 or 3` from a file. I am also adjusting the text to fill the complete label. If the text is small, then its font size need to be increase and if it is large then it need to be small font size.

I am using stylesheet to make the background color of label to black and I am putting it after adjusting the font size of the text. Like below:

```
void MainWindow::SerialRead()
{
   //Reading the serial data
   //Reading the string from file
   //Adjusting the font size to fill the label

   //Changing color
   ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel{ background-color : black; color : white; }");
}
```

So after this my outcome looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the above image, there is white border which is of main window because we have not set the back color of main window (it is not clearly visible because webpage color is also white). I also want the color of main window to be black so that full screen is black and text is white. I also tried setting the stylesheet in main.c for main window like below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow app;
  //Chaning color
  app.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {background-color : black;}");
  app.SerialInit();
  app.SerialWrite();
  app.showFullScreen();

  return a.exec();
}
```

So it does changes the color of main window to black but the outcome looks like below:

[image]

As you can see it also changes the font size of the text which I do not want. How can I achieve this.?

Comment: Maybe it's not necessary to change background colour of the main window. It could be enought to remove spacing / set the label to cover all the area of the main window.

Comment: @ni1ight I have already set the layout of label to layout in a grid. Is there any other way

Comment: @ni1ight As per this question, i tried the solution but it didnt worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129324/qt-widget-with-layout-space-what-is-it-how-to-remove

Comment: The size of your label should not have anything to do with your background color! is the label inside a layout ? If so what is the SizeConstraint flag?

Comment: @basslo FIrst I have a MainWindow then there is a central widget and then there is the label. I have not set any SizeConstraint. I have just set the layout of the MainWindow to layout in a grid, so the label has stretched fully to main window

Comment: @annacarolina Maybe changing these settings for the layout might help: https://wiki.qt.io/Adjust_Spacing_and_Margins_between_Widgets_in_Layout
Also why do you change stylesheet of the label in the "SerialRead()" function? Should be enough to set it once in a contructor of the MainWindow.

Comment: @ni1ight yes I know it should be in construtor but then the output looks like in the 2nd image. I do not know why

Comment: @ni1ight Thanks for the link. By setting the margin to 0, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also new in qt , but I can suggest you to  first set a name of `QMainWindow` by `setObjectName` and then use style sheet as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow app;
  //Chaning color
  app.setStyleSheet("#MainWindowName{background-color : black;}");
  app.SerialInit();
  app.SerialWrite();
  app.showFullScreen();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Hope it helps.