# How to create custom panel without framing via Python in Nuke？

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, nuke

Could you tell me how to create custom panel in NUKE having no spacing (i.e. frameless window)?

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: setContentsMargin, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129324/qt-widget-with-layout-space-what-is-it-how-to-remove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the panel has several nested widgets each adding their own margin, so you'll need to iterate through the parent widgets and setContentsMargins on each.

```
"""
Get rid of the margins surrounding custom Panels
"""

import nuke
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
from nukescripts import panels

def set_widget_margins_to_zero(widget_object):

    if widget_object:
        target_widgets = set()
        target_widgets.add(widget_object.parentWidget().parentWidget())
        target_widgets.add(widget_object.parentWidget().parentWidget().parentWidget().parentWidget())

        for widget_layout in target_widgets:
            try:
                widget_layout.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            except:
                pass

class Example_Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Margins be-gone!')
        label.setStyleSheet('QLabel{background: #eeffcc}')

        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        expandingPolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        label.setSizePolicy(expandingPolicy)
        self.setSizePolicy(expandingPolicy)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.Show:

            try:
                set_widget_margins_to_zero(self)
            except:
                pass

        return QtGui.QWidget.event(self, event)

panels.registerWidgetAsPanel('Example_Window', 'Example Widget',
                             'mwbp.Example_Widget')
```

to give credit where it's due, I found the solution a while ago here : https://gist.github.com/maty974/4739917 and have posted an integrated example widget.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a panel that I know via Python is this (but it's with frame):

```
class myCustomPanel( nukescripts.PythonPanel ):

    def __init__( self ):

        nukescripts.PythonPanel.__init__( self, 'myCustomPanel' )
        self.update = nuke.PyScript_Knob( 'update', 'Update Info' )
        self.info = nuke.Multiline_Eval_String_Knob( 'info', 'Info' )
        self.info.setEnabled( True )
        self.addKnob( self.update )
        self.addKnob( self.info )

def addInfoPanel():

    global iPanel
    iPanel = myCustomPanel()
    return iPanel.addToPane()

paneMenu = nuke.menu( 'Pane' )
paneMenu.addCommand( 'myCustomPanel', addInfoPanel )
```

[image]